# Why does an increase in terminal voltage cause current to decrease?

Tags: electricity

This is part of a lab report that I'm writing and I don't really know why an increase in terminal voltage would cause a decrease in current. I have derived this mathematically, and through the data I've collected but, I'd like to know conceptually why this happens. Thanks in advance! And feel free to ask any additional questions!

Comment: "I have derived this mathematically" - can you elaborate on this point?

Comment: @probably_someone, well what I meant by that was that I got the data and plotted a best fit line. And because the slope was negative you could say "mathematically" that they were negatively correlated.

Comment: Ok, then can you elaborate on what kind of power supply you're using? The way the question is written, it currently sounds like you're using a power supply where you can manipulate the output voltage at will (based on the fact that you say an increase in terminal voltage _causes_ a decrease in current), which rules out things like a battery.

Comment: @probably_someone yeah it's a power supply where the voltage can be manipulated. You have a knob, which you turn to change the output voltage. But I don't think that the question should be limited to my lab. Just generally why is it that an increase in terminal voltage will cause a decrease in current.

Comment: Without knowing the details of the power supply (i.e. what mode was being used, what the voltage and current limits are, etc.) and without knowing the output voltage and current ranges you collected data on, it's going to be very difficult to answer this question.

Comment: Based on your additional information in response to probably someone's question, my answer does not apply so I have deleted it.

Comment: Generally, increasing terminal voltages doesn't decrease the current. But there are some specific circuits that have this behavior. If you want us to be able to answer why it happened in your case, you need to share the circuit you were studying.